# Strategies for syncing deleted records

Tags: soql, rest-api

We want to keep our system up to date with the status of various objects, should they become deleted.

What's the best strategy for doing this?
Could we sync records where LastModified was yesterday, and check if IsDeleted is true?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOAP [getDeleted()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm), REST [/sobjects/*sObjectName*/deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm), or Apex [Database.getDeleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_getDeleted) to get records that are deleted within a certain time frame within the past 15 days. These methods will return Ids for deleted records for the named object. Note that records purged from the Recycle Bin are not returned. You should use the Replication API methods above if you want to strictly ensure you do not miss any records.

*(Edit: this API now only includes records still in the Recycle Bin; I'm pretty sure this is new behavior.)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check for lastModified and isDeleted. Different approaches can be taken depending on the use case, and requirements.

Records obtained using the Rest API have the isDeleted attribute, which you already mentioned. So, that would be 1 way of doing it, another would be to perform a REST callout to your app when records are deleted. Or periodically perform a status check the params you mentioned.